# teb_local_planner compilation error

Tags: ros, teb-local-planner, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS:kinetic:

[image: image description]

error:

```
teb_local_planner_ros.cpp:229:40: error: no matching function for call to ‘costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS::getRobotPose(tf::Stampedtf::Transform&)’
costmap_ros_->getRobotPose(robot_pose);

/opt/ros/kinetic/include/class_loader/meta_object.hpp:198:16: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘teb_local_planner::TebLocalPlannerROS’
return new C;
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329601/teb_local_planner-compilation-error/) by [Tansor](https://answers.ros.org/users/39183/tansor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2019-07-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like you are mixing kinetic and melodic sources.
The method

```
virtual void initialize(std::string name, tf2_ros::Buffer* tf, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros) = 0;
```

from `nav_core` ([see here](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/melodic-devel/nav_core/include/nav_core/base_local_planner.h#L78)) is pure virtual and not implemented in teb_local_planner according to your build log.
The method indicates the tf2 dependency which was introduced to ROS navigation and teb_local_planner in `melodic`.
So it seems that you are trying to compile the `kinetic` version of teb_local_planner with the `melodic` version of the navigation stack.
Make sure to clone the correct branch, e.g. for melodic:

```
git clone -b melodic-devel https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation.git
git clone -b melodic-devel https://github.com/rst-tu-dortmund/teb_local_planner.git
```

Or use the correct ROS distribution for your APT repositories.

---

Originally posted by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) with karma: 2531 on 2019-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/301392/navfn-compile-error/) addresses a similar problem.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2019-07-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2